# How to index individual layers from a SpatRaster object by time?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I found out the other day, more or less by chance, that it is possible to query layers from SpatRaster objects based on the time attribute in general (c.f. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/437338/145307)), e.g based on years (`r["2017"]`) and yearmonths (`r["2017-10"]`).

Now I wanted to deep-dive a little bit into this because of the great flexibility you receive when working with spatio-temporal data. Unfortunately, I seem to be failing from the beginning and can't reproduce the behaviour from before because of the following error: `[subset] no (valid) layer selected`

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.3

r <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, nlyr = 365)


time(r) <- seq(from = as.POSIXlt("2001-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
               to = as.POSIXlt("2001-12-31", tz = "UTC"),
               by = "day")

r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 10, 10, 365  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> time        : 2001-01-01 to 2001-12-31 UTC

time(r) |> class()
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

r["2001"]
#> Error: [subset] no (valid) layer selected


time(r) <- as.Date("2002-01-01") + 0:364

r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 10, 10, 365  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> time (days) : 2002-01-01 to 2002-12-31

time(r) |> class()
#> [1] "Date"

r["2002"]
#> Error: [subset] no (valid) layer selected
```

I had a look at `?time` as well as at the docs at [rspatial.org](https://rspatial.org/terra/index.html) but was not able to find relevant documentation related to indexing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Or `r[[grep('^2001-01', time(r))]]` as an example and wrap with names(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up layer names (that may look like a time-stamp) with an actual time-stamp.

Here is how you can use time-stamps (using Date here, as it is a bit less verbose)

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, nlyr = 365)
time(r) <- as.Date("2001-01-01") + 0:364
head(names(r))
# "lyr.1" "lyr.2" "lyr.3" "lyr.4" "lyr.5" "lyr.6"
```

You can subset layers by name like this

```
r[["lyr.1"]]
```

Note the double brackets for sub-setting layers, although you can use single brackets when using a name as opposed to a numerical index.

To subset by time, you can do

```
r[[time(r) == as.Date("2001-06-01")]]
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#time (days) : 2001-06-01
```

With dates, you do not even need to use "as.Date"

```
r[[time(r) >= "2001-12-01"]]
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 31  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#time (days) : 2001-12-01 to 2001-12-31
```

Comment: Ah, I see what I did there unconsciously. With `names(r)` being `c("2017-09", "2017-10", "2017-11", ...)` I was able to query them as intended because of partial matching. Tricky! Thank you very much! Having worked with `xts` a lot in the past months I was somehow expecting the z-dimension of the stack to be the time automatically, but that's not true of course for multi-layered raster data. Ok, think I'll consider setting names per default in the future to enable partial matching - and maybe also write some kind of a `subset()` to accept indexing via `"2001-01-01/2001-03-31"` like xts does.